# Closed, bounded interval

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Theorem 3.39 of *An Introduction to Analysis* by W. R. Wade is:

> Suppose that $I$ is a closed, bounded interval. If $f : I \to \mathbf{R}$ is continuous on $I$, then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $I$.

Is there such a thing as a closed, unbounded interval?

Comment: Yes: all intervals of the forms $[a,\to)$ and $(\leftarrow,a]$ are closed and unbounded, and so is $\Bbb R$. These are all of the closed, unbounded intervals.

Comment: How about $(0, 1)$? @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @user129393192 $(0,1)$ is bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for example the interval $ [0, \infty)$ is clearly unbounded, and is closed in $\mathbb{R}$ because its complement is $(-\infty, 0)$ is open.

Comment: What do you say about intervals like $(0, 1]$?

Comment: @user129393192: That interval is bounded, and neither closed nor open.