# closed and bounded interval

Tags: real-analysis

I am a bit confused about the concept of a "closed and bounded interval"

I have a theorem:

if $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then $f$ is uniformly continuous

My teacher pronounces this as "closed and bounded interval"

What does this mean?

Specifically, I think for example: $[0, 1)$ is bounded and half-closed and $[0, \infty)$ is unbounded and half-closed.

so does *closed* refer to both ends being $[ ]$ and $bounded$ refers to if there exists $M > 0$ s.t for $x \in [a,b]$, $|x| < M$ (i.e, the usual definition)?

related but not a duplicate: [Closed, bounded interval](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208684/closed-bounded-interval)

Comment: YES and YES. Both are correct.

Comment: $(-\infty,\infty)$ is closed but not bounded

Comment: So is that the only exception @J.W.Tanner ? Also, how can it contain all its limit points if it doesn't contain $\infty$? I am in real analysis for reference, have not studied topology.

Comment: $[a,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,b]$ are also closed but not bounded intervals.

Comment: In $~\Bbb{R}, ~$ an interval is closed if and only if its complement is open.  Also, the empty set is open, because (trivially) every element in the empty set is an interior point.

Answer (score 2):

Repeat 100 times in your mind while reading this answer: *$\infty$ is not a number*.

Intuitively you can think of an interval as being *closed* if it contains each of its **finite** endpoints, meaning each of its endpoints that is an actual *number* (... $\infty$ is not a number ...). This is consistent with the topologist's definition saying that a subset of $\mathbb R$ is closed if and only if it contains each of its limit points in $\mathbb R$ (... *$\infty$ is not a number, $\infty$ is not a number* ...)

So the intervals $[a,+\infty)$ and $(-\infty,b]$ and $(-\infty,+\infty)$ are, indeed, closed: $[a,+\infty)$ contains its unique finite endpoint $a$; and $(-\infty,b]$ contains its unique finite endpoint $b$; and $(-\infty,+\infty)$ has no finite endpoints at all and therefore it (vacuously) contains each of them (... *$\infty$ is not a number* ...)